# LINQ: Split string to List<string>

Tags: linq, split

Hi i started to work with linq and i have some trouble to split an string:

This is the string:

a;b;cod1;xx|a;b;cod2;xx|a;b;cod3;xx|a;b;cod4;xx

first i split the sring by the '|' character so i got this result

```
a;b;cod1;xx
a;b;cod2;xx
a;b;cod3;xx
a;b;cod4;xx
```

and then i split again by the ';' in the second index to have this result in to a list

```
cod1
cod2
cod3
cod4
```

so there is a better way to do this using linq ¿?

Thanks!

Comment: Linq does not fix everything!

Comment: Not really, you'd still end up splitting into collections similar to what you've already done to be able to use Linq over the collections.

Comment: Yes i know that maybe could exist a best solution to this, but i try to use linq to avoid the use of two or more loops (for or foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select` to put your code into one line (but you still have to use `String.Split`):

```
var s = "a;b;cod1;xx|a;b;cod2;xx|a;b;cod3;xx|a;b;cod4;xx";
var resultlist = s.Split('|').Select(x => x.Split(';')[2]).ToList();
```

so you don't have to use `for`/`foreach` loops.

Comment: Yes that solution was the first that i code... but it trhows an exception:

"Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: @RamiroNavaCastro, then the data you are using isn't the data you've posted in your question.

Comment: That means you have items in your input string that don't follow this pattern `a;b;codX;xx`

Comment: Thats true the string that i was getting it have a bad format. Thanks BigYellowCactus to point the error.